# Integral of sum of two sine waves

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose two phase-shifted cosine waves (lets say they are almost in antiphase and  have a phase shift of 170 deg). Their sum produces a new sinusoid. What is the integral over the amplitude of the sum wave? Background: I need to know for two discrete signals what their average/sum amplitude is in dependence on their phase shift and variances.

Answer (score 1):

$y=\sin \left( x \right)$ and $y=\sin \left( x-\frac{170\pi }{180} \right)$ are the two waves with the latter shifted; phase=170º.

Now the sum is:
$$y=\sin \left( x \right)+\sin \left( x-\frac{17\pi }{18} \right)$$

Let's find two adjacent x intercepts to integrate:

$\sin \left( x \right)+\sin \left( x-\frac{17\pi }{18} \right)=0$

$x=\frac{17\pi }{18}-x+2\pi k,\; k\; belongs\; to\; Z$

$x=\frac{17\pi }{36}+\pi k$

I'll take k=0 and k=1:

$$x=\frac{17\pi }{36},\frac{53\pi }{36}$$

Now we integrate:

$$\int_{\frac{17\pi }{36}}^{\frac{53\pi }{36}}{\sin \left( x \right)+\sin \left( x-\frac{17\pi }{18} \right)dx=2\left( \cos \left( \frac{17\pi }{36} \right)-\cos \left( \frac{19\pi }{36} \right) \right)}$$

which is approximately 0.348623

Here's an image of the shaded area:

[image]